# New IIS 7 site not loading any PHP/HTML pages

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, laravel-5.1, fastcgi

we have an IIS 7 server hosting different sites/applications.
Take not that this server is hosting other site/site-applications running on either asp or php. There is already an existing site application running thru fastCGI php.

I now added a new site (not a site-application) - a laravel 5.1 framework, to the IIS server, but this new site is not loading anything. Tried a test php page which echos `phpinfo()` only and i also made a static html file with just "Hello world" on it but to no avail.

Checked my handlers, and my php handler is there.

When i try to browse the sites host name I get this error:

```
The server at [mysubdom].[domain].com can't be found, because the DNS
lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to
its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to
the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an 
unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing 
the network.
```

Is this really a DNS problem?

Comment: You will have to post relevant config files. `<sites>` in applicationHost.config is the key to start.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open it local? http://127.0.0.1/{websitename}/index.html with the hello world ... Don't always go directly to your binding address.. try to load on the server itself first.